# Why am I getting an "invalid token" error in the GraphQL playground/IDE?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql, graphql-js

I'm using graphql-yoga server, Express, Node.js, Prisma client and Prisma server. And trying to do a post mutation to a GraphQL server using the GraphQL playground. However, I'm getting a persistent error "invalid token" which seems to span from my `getUSerId` helper function that's called on most Mutation field resolver functions.

Here is a code snippet of the error

```js
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "invalid token",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "post"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the code to my resolver function in utils.js

```js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const APP_SECRET = "GraphQL-is-aw3some";

function getUserId(context) {
  const Authorization = context.request.get("Authorization");

  if (Authorization) {
    const token = Authorization.replace("Bearer", "");
    const { userId } = jwt.verify(token, APP_SECRET);
    return userId;
  }
  throw new Error("Not Authenticated");
}

module.exports = {
  APP_SECRET,
  getUserId
};
```

Here is code for my post resolver function

```js
function post(parent, args, context, info) {
  const userId = getUserId(context);
  return context.prisma.createLink({
    url: args.url,
    description: args.description,
    postedBy: { connect: { id: userId } }
  });
}
```

Here is my mutation in the playground

```js
mutation{
  post(
    description: "Prisma repalces traditional ORMs"
    url: "www.prisma.io"
  ){
    id
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you changed `request.credentials` to `include` or `same-origin` in your playground settings?

Comment: @DanielRearden I actually just realized request.credentials has an "omit" value. Could this be the problem?

Comment: @DanielRearden I just tried it and it still failed. The error persists

Comment: @DanielRearden to be more specific, I'm getting a JsonWebTokenError in the terminal

Comment: I actually found the bug. Thanks for the effort.